# Workbench Error, specified driver class not be found

Tags: sql-server-2008, workbench

I am trying to connect my SQL database using workbench and it gives me,

"specified driver class not be found" error !!

though it connects other oracle database on the same. What all configurations I need to check to get it connected.

Comment: This question is missing details, please be more specific.

Comment: I an not sure what specific detail you might be looking for, if possible please point out that...I will definatly mention.